# I need help on Geofence or Geofire on Android

Tags: java, android, gps, device, geofire

Whenever my device goes inside the geofence I want the `sendNotificationsToEveryone()` to be triggered or `sendNotificationsToEveryoneExit()` triggered depending on the scenario.

This is the function triggering section of my code:

```
geoQueryArray[geoFireCount] = geoFire.queryAtLocation(new GeoLocation(geofirelocations.latitude, geofirelocations.longitude), 0.1f);
            geoQueryArray[geoFireCount].addGeoQueryEventListener(new GeoQueryEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onKeyEntered(String key, GeoLocation location) {
                    sendNotificationsToEveryone(fcm_tokens_list, geoName);
                }

                @Override
                public void onKeyExited(String key) {
                    sendNotificationsToEveryoneExit(fcm_tokens_list,geoName);
                }

                @Override
                public void onKeyMoved(String key, GeoLocation location) {
                    Log.d("MOVE", String.format("%s move within the dangerous area [%f/%f]", key, location.latitude, location.longitude));
                    //sendNotificationsExit(fcm_tokens_list);
                }

                @Override
                public void onGeoQueryReady() {

                }

                @Override
                public void onGeoQueryError(DatabaseError error) {
                    Log.d("ERROR", ""+error);
                }
            });
            geoFireCount++;
```

and this is my code for the Device that when it goes inside the Geofence, it should trigger the sendNotifications functions:

```
  final double latitude = Double.parseDouble(part1);
  final double longitude = Double.parseDouble(part2);

    geoFire1.setLocation("You", new GeoLocation(latitude, longitude), new GeoFire.CompletionListener() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(String key, DatabaseError error) {
            if (mCurrent != null)
                mCurrent.remove();

            BitmapDescriptor deviceIcon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.watchdevice);

            mCurrent = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                    .position(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
                    .title("GPS Device").icon(deviceIcon));
            LatLng coordinate = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
            CameraUpdate yourLocation = CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(coordinate, 12);
            mMap.animateCamera(yourLocation);
        }
    });
```

This code are in the same file, I wonder how I will edit the `geoQueryArray[]` to include the Device that when it goes inside the geofence the `sendNotications` functions will be triggered.

Comment: i think adding geofences will work better

Comment: What do mean abdul, putting another geofire code under the device?

Comment: yeah, add Geo fences against each location. When user move inside or outside of the location, a broadcast will be triggered.
following is the link for an example app : https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Geofencing/#readme